# Expresión regular que obtenga los registros con alguno de estos caracteres: ~ ` ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ + = { } [ ] | \ / : ; " ' <

Tags: oracle, regex

A ver si alguien podría decirme.

Estoy intentando obtener una expresión regular en Oracle para obtener todos los registros que contengan al menos uno de los siguientes caracteres ~ ` ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ + = { } [ ] | \ / : ; " ' <

Pero estoy teniendo especialmente problemas a la hora de ver qué caracteres escapar y cuales no, y también a la hora de usar los corchetes con la negación ([^]). Lo que yo estaba probando era algo similar a la siguiente instrucción (pongo solo algunos caracteres de ejemplo):

```
SELECT * 
FROM DUAL 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('AA#', '[^~`!@#]');
```

Según mi lógica eso no debería devolver resultados porque le estoy diciendo que saque los valores que no tienen entre otros el carácter # y sin embargo ese literal (AA#) sí que lo tiene, imagino que no estoy usando bien la expresión. Si alguien pudiera echarme una mano para obtener la expresión regular con todos los caracteres se lo agradecería.

Gracias!

Comment: En el WHERE estás poniendo condiciones sobre lo que va en el select. No sería mejor poner el ejemplo en el SELECT, quitar el where y ver qué pasa?

Comment: ¿No te sale mejor hacer un `... WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (la_columna, '^[0-9 a-zA-Z]+$') ...` tal como [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079657/1545868) (en inglés)?.

Comment: @aeportugal Eso dejaría un sin fin de caracteres fuera, incluyendo emojis, vocales con acento, etc.

Comment: @aeportugal Podría hacer eso que mencionas (WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (la_columna, '^[0-9 a-zA-Z]+$'), pero entonces estaría excluyendo caracteres que no quiero excluir. Lo que busco es únicamente excluir los caracteres mencionados en el enunciado.

Answer (score 0):

> `` [^~`!@#] ``
> no debería devolver resultados porque le estoy diciendo que saque los
> valores que no tienen entre otros el carácter `#` y sin embargo ese
> literal `AA#` sí que lo tiene

No exactamente. Al contrario, estás buscando todos los textos que tengan al menos 1 caracter que sea cualquiera menos `` ~`!@# `` (y claramente una `A` **es** un caracter que **no es** uno de esos símbolos).

En cambio, conviene intentar encontrar a esos símbolos, y negar el resultado final:

```
--...
where not REGEXP_LIKE( Campo, '[\-~`!@#$%^&*()_+={}\[\]|\\\\/:;"''<]')
```